# JSon Schema to XSD - Patterns of OneOf not retained

Tags: java, json, xsd, transformation

I'm currently trying to convert an Json Schema to an XSD file "on-the-fly", and I've just noticed....a less than ideal bug.

I've noticed that patterns of the strings produced by the below schema (and other schemas too) aren't transferred across, and unsure of the root of the bug.

Java Code Snippet:

```
public String convertJsonToXsd(String json, String name) throws IOException, TransformerException {
    final Config cfg = new Config.Builder().targetNamespace("http://example.com/myschema.xsd")
            .rootElement(name)
            .name(name)
            .ignoreUnknownFormats(true).build();
    Reader jsonReader = new StringReader(json);
    final Document doc = Jsons2Xsd.convert(jsonReader, cfg);
    jsonReader.close();
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(sw);
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    transformer.transform(domSource, sr);
    String constructed = sw.toString();
    return constructed;
}
```

Json Schema Snippet:

```
{"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#","title":"Example using definitions and references","type":"object","properties":{"from":{"$ref":"#/definitions/timestampDef"},"to":{"$ref":"#/definitions/timestampDef"}},"definitions":{"timestampDef":{"type":"string","oneOf":[{"pattern":"^now([+-][0-9]+[smhdMy])?$"},{"pattern":"^[0-9]{12,14}$"}]}}}
```

Edit 1

This Uses the Jsons2XSD code for the Config block. Everything else is basic Java/ORG Xml Code

Produced XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><schema xmlns:x="http://example.com/myschema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/myschema.xsd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><element name="JsonToXSDSchema" type="x:JsonToXSDSchema"/><complexType name="JsonToXSDSchema"><sequence><element minOccurs="0" name="from" type="x:timestampDef"/><element minOccurs="0" name="to" type="x:timestampDef"/></sequence></complexType><simpleType name="timestampDef"><restriction base="string"/></simpleType></schema>
```

Edit 2:

For reference to the examples, the timestamp patterns don't get carried across to the XSD, just the Object type of String.

Comment: Probably giving an concrete example of what you are noticing might help in this situation.  Because the Produced XSD, look fine to me, so what is wrong with it might help shed more light.

Comment: @NiteRain if you notice in the json schema, there's two patterns for the timestamp def, but in the xsd there's just a string literal. I'd have expected the patterns to be carried over into XSD.

Comment: Sounds like a straightforward bug in whatever tool you are using to convert from JSON schema to XML schema. I'm not sure that anybody on this forum can help - you will need to contact the developers of the tool.